# why onCreate() is called every time when its started activity is finished?

Tags: android, android-fragments

In my app, there is a activity A, which it's a main activity, also there are several fragments inside A. When you click the images in one of fragments, it will start a new Activity B. When you click back button, i will call finish() to finish the activity and return to Activity A. But when returning to the Activity A, onCreate() of A is called again. Why onCreate() is called each time? As i know, it should be just called once, and then onStart() should be called.

From segment to the Activity B is as below:

```
Intent i = new Intent(_scontext, ProductListing.class);
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
_scontext.startActivity(i);
getActivity().overridePendingTransition(R.anim.push_out_to_left,R.anim.push_out_to_right);
```

When click back button in the Activity B, the code snippet is as following:

```
Intent _gobck = new Intent(_ctx,ProductDisplay.class);
startActivity(_gobck);
finish();
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.push_out_to_left,
    R.anim.push_out_to_right);
```

What's wrong with the code? Am i missing anything?

Comment: there is no need to start the activity again. to go back to the previous activity call `finish()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are starting the activity again. **Remove** the following code and it will work.

```
Intent _gobck = new Intent(_ctx,ProductDisplay.class);
startActivity(_gobck);
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you already got your answer by @Rajitha Siriwardena but i just want to clear some of the points here,

> As i know, it should be just called once, and then onStart() should
>   be called.

Above sentence is not a true first of all .

There is possibility to for your `ActivityA` to go in `OnCreate` even if you finish your `ActivityB`. If your ActivityB stay in foreground for a long time ,of-course your ActivityA will be in background in that case , so ultimately your Activity in `onStop` (remember not in `onPause`) and android [Activity life cycle doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) says, after `onStop` if your app want reach your Activity then it will goes in `onCreate`

So `finish()` `ActivityB` would work but there is no guarantee to your `ActivityA` called `onCreate` when you do so .

Answer (score 1):

if you remove finish() from your backPress Activity will not be created and you don't need to write  Intent it will manage it's back stack it self.